# Can I use views_bulk_operations with the D7 core toolbar module?

Tags: nodes, views

I'm building a site right now where I'd prefer to use views_bulk_operations to administer the standard content overview (admin/content) and user overview pages (admin/people). My trouble is that I also want to use the toolbar module (or something like it) to give my site admins the ability to easily browse to the pages generated by views_bulk_operations (admin/content2 and admin/people2). It doesn't seem possible right now.

Any ideas? Or, perhaps, any alternatives to the core toolbar module? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how I want to do it: http://drupal.org/project/quickbar

The Quickbar module allows me to provide an administration bar at the top of the page, much like the default toolbar, but I get to define what menu is placed in that bar. It will allow me to keep the content admins away from the default content admin pages by simply not providing a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal core toolbar gives you only the top-level menu items anyway, so you could use [Admin Menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) to give you a dropdown style toolbar (I personally like Admin Menu + Admin Menu Toolbar style; disable core Toolbar module).

Create your VBO pages with a path emulating the core administration paths (e.g. admin/content/vbo1) and create menu items for those views in the Administration menu. That should do it.

Comment: That's not quite going to do it. I don't want to provide access to *both* places via the admin menu... that would be confusing for the content admin's. I'd be happy to use the admin_menu module, but it suffers from the same problem as the toolbar module, ie. that the menu items appear based on permissions.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what part wouldn't work for you. If I'm misunderstanding, please elaborate the question. 1) Do I understand correctly that you do want dropdown items in the toolbar? 2a) Can't you just disable the 'Content' menu item under Content management (in the Administration menu) if you don't want to confuse the admins with similar menu items? 2b) Or alternatively, not give them the 'Administer content' permission (since you are replacing that functionality with VBO)? And similarly not assign the 'Administer users' permission if you leave that to a VBO page?

Comment: 1) Dropdown menu items per se is not the point, no. 2a) That's my whole problem: I can't simply disable the "content" menu item in the admin_menu module. The only way to do it (and this also answers 2b) is to **not** give them the ability to 'administer content'... but that's not what I want to do. (If you know another way, let me know.) I **want** my content admins to administer content; I just don't want them to use the default content administration page.

Comment: I see you're right that disabling the menu item doesn't just work with admin_menu. As for the permissions: the idea is that you let the admins use VBO pages to administer the content, so they no longer _need_ to have that permission in order to administer content (but you have to restrict access to the VBO view based on role). But if Quickbar works for you... You may also be interested in the [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) suite of modules, BTW.